Taylor expansion of extrinsic Euclidean distance in terms of intrinsic Riemannian distance
Let $x\in (M^d,g) \subset \mathbb{R}^p,$ an embedded $d$-dimensional Riemannian submanifold of $ \mathbb{R}^p.$ Let us take the Euclidean ball $B_{\mathbb{R}^p}(x;\delta),$ and a point $y\in M$ in it. So $y\in M \cap B_{\mathbb{R}^p}(x;\delta).$
Next choose a normal coordinate system in a small neighborhood caround $x$ contained in $B_{\mathbb{R}^p}(x;\delta)$, i.e., orthonormal tangent vectors $(E_1\dots E_d)$ in $T_xM.$ Take $log_{x}y:=(exp_x(y))^{-1}\in T_xM = \sum_{i=1}^{d}u_iE_i,$ where $u_i'$s are the normal coordinates of $y.$ Then the Euclidean norm of the vector $u:=(u_1\dots u_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is the tangent space norm of $log_{x}y: ||log_{x}y||_{T_xM}^2=||u||_{\mathbb{R}^d}^2= \sum_{i=1}^{d}u_i^2.$
We know, e.g. see this, $d_M^2(x,y)= ||log_{x}y||_{T_xM}^2 + O(||log_{x}y||_{T_xM}^4)= ||u||_{\mathbb{R}^d}^2 + O(||u||_{\mathbb{R}^d}^4), ||u||_{\mathbb{R}^d} < \delta$ when $\delta$ above is small enough.
But is there such an expansion connecting the extrinsic distance $||x-y||_{\mathbb{R}^p}^2$ with the intrinsic distance $||u||_{\mathbb{R}^d}^2?$ I'm guessing this'll involve the second fundamental form, but I haven't seen any formula in the standard textbooks yet. References and/or derivations appreciated.
Thanks to the hint/suggestion by @Deane, I calculated as follows:
let $\gamma:[0,s]\to M$ be a unit speed geodesic with $\gamma(0)=x, \gamma(s)=y.$ Then Taylor expanding $\gamma(s)\in \mathbb{R}^p$ around $0$ gives us:
$||y-x||^2_{\mathbb{R}^p} = ||\gamma(s)-\gamma(0)||^2_{\mathbb{R}^p}= (s^2||\gamma'(0)||^2+ O(s^2))^2= ||\gamma'(0)||^2s^2 + O(s^3).$ But since $||\gamma'(0)||=1$ because of the unit speed assumption, we get:
$$||x-y||^2_{\mathbb{R}^p}=d^2(x,y)+ O(d^3(x,y)).$$
Is this correct and can this be improved? If $\gamma$ is a geodesic in $M,$ then its all of its tangential components will vanish leaving only the normal component, but I'm not sure this information helps with refining the Taylor expansion (meaning dropping a few terms of lower order).
Thanks again!

I suggest working out the details for $d=1$ and $p=2$. That will give you an idea of what to expect in higher dimensions.

@Deane Sorry but could you please give a hint? Thanks in advance!

Rewrite your question for that case. It’s just a curve in the plane. So all these fancy words and symbols turn into the basic stuff you learned about curves in multivariable calculus or elementary differential geometry.

Show your work for this case and we can help you with it.

@Deane I just showed the work in details with a few relevant comments. Could you please see if this is okay and if not, can it be made better?

You can write the second order Taylor series in terms of the normal curvature of $\gamma$, which in turn depends only on the second fundamental form of $M$ and the direction of $\gamma$. Note that if $d < p-1$, then normal curvature is a vector and not a scalar. I still recommend working this out in the special case I suggested above.
